# Using jq and outputting specific columns with formatting

Tags: sorting, dictionary, curl, select, jq

Can anyone help me to understand how I can print countryCode followed by connectionName and load with a percentage symbol all on one line nicely formatted - all using jq - not using sed, column or any other unix external command. I cannot seem print anything other than the one column

curl --silent "https://api.surfshark.com/v3/server/clusters" | jq -r -c "map(select(.countryCode == "US" and .load <= "99")) | sort_by(.load) | limit(20;.[]) | [.countryCode, .connectionName, .load] | (.[1])

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted ?

```
curl --silent "https://api.surfshark.com/v3/server/clusters" | 
    jq -r -c 'map(select(.countryCode == "US" and .load <= 99)) |
              sort_by(.load) |
              limit(20;.[]) |
              "\(.countryCode) \(.connectionName) \(.load)%"'
```